# How to solve infinite loop in going through a table with cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored process that doesn't work, every time I run it it stays in an infinite loop. The objective of the SP is to go through the table of products for each row to evaluate the result and if the result when counting the rows is greater than 0, the code must be inserted in a table, if the result is 0 the record must be inserted according to the third query.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT @QUERY = count (*)  from (
SELECT TOP 1  [ID],[code],[FEC_MAX],[FUENTE]FROM PRODUCTO
  WHERE ( FUENTE = 1 OR FUENTE =2 OR FUENTE = 3 ) and code = @CODE
  order by  FEC_MAX DESC 
  ) a 

IF @QUERY > 0
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TEST
    SELECT @code,@fecha,@NOMBRE, @FUENTE , @ID ;
END
if @QUERY < 0
    INSERT INTO TEST
    SELECT top 1  @code,@fecha,@NOMBRE, @FUENTE , @ID
    FROM TEST
    WHERE  code = @code
    order by  FUENTE ASC

END
```

THNKS

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @RobertKock  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: I see `@@FETCH_STATUS` but I don't see a cursor.  What would be helpful to us is if the example could simply be copy/pasted and run.  Or if you setup something with SQL fiddle for us to try.  I suspect in trying to write a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example you may find your issue.

Comment: That might be the problem. There is nothing in the body of the loop that is going to change `@@FETCH_STATUS ` as it doesn't do any cursor operations at all

Comment: @MartinSmith I have this OPEN #P FETCH NEXT FROM #P INTO 
  at the beginning of the cursor

Comment: @Thomas any luck with the solution below?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing FETCH NEXT FROM inside your loop.

Return Value from @@FETCHSTATUS

- 0 Fetch statement successful
- -1 Fetch statement failed or the row was beyond the result set
- -2 The row fetched is missing.
- -9 The cursor is not performing a fetch operation.

The cursor is stuck on the first row and @@FETCHSTATUS will always return successful. Add FETCH NEXT FROM inside your loop as below assuming you have declared your cursor correctly. It should look somethign like this:

```
DECLARE YourCursorName CURSOR FOR  
SELECT col
FROM PRODUCTO
OPEN YourCursorName;  
FETCH NEXT FROM YourCursorName;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT @QUERY = count (*)  from (
SELECT TOP 1  [ID],[code],[FEC_MAX],[FUENTE]FROM PRODUCTO
  WHERE ( FUENTE = 1 OR FUENTE =2 OR FUENTE = 3 ) and code = @CODE
  order by  FEC_MAX DESC 
  ) a 

IF @QUERY > 0
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TEST
    SELECT @code,@fecha,@NOMBRE, @FUENTE , @ID ;
END
if @QUERY < 0
    INSERT INTO TEST
    SELECT top 1  @code,@fecha,@NOMBRE, @FUENTE , @ID
    FROM TEST
    WHERE  code = @code
    order by  FUENTE ASC

FETCH NEXT FROM YourCursorName

END
CLOSE YourCursorName;  
DEALLOCATE YourCursorName;
```